# setting background color of a button not working

Tags: android, drawable, android-button

I have a layout, which has a button:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@color/frontcolor">

<androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
    android:id="@+id/toolbar_top"
    android:layout_height="45dp"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:background="@color/frontcolor" >

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="left"
        android:src="@drawable/flecha"
        android:id="@+id/flecha"/>


    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:id="@+id/toolbar_title"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:textColor="@color/white"/>


</androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar>

<ScrollView
    android:id="@+id/scrollview"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/toolbar_top"
    android:layout_marginTop="90dp">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/inner_rl"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="@string/recoverpassword"
            android:textColor="@color/white" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/email"
            android:layout_width="250dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:layout_below="@+id/tv"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:background="@drawable/round_edittext"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:hint="@string/email"
            android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
            android:padding="5dp"
            android:textColor="@color/frontcolor"
            android:textColorHint="@color/frontcolor" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/sendbutton"
            android:layout_width="250dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:layout_below="@+id/email"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:background="@drawable/buttonshapewhite"
            android:text="@string/send"
            android:textColor="@color/frontcolor"
            android:alpha="0.2"/>
    </RelativeLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Specifically, is sendButton the View I have problems with. I am setting a drawable as a background:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:shape="rectangle" >
<corners
    android:radius="30dp"
    />
<solid
    android:color="@color/white"
    />
<padding
    android:left="0dp"
    android:top="0dp"
    android:right="0dp"
    android:bottom="0dp"
    />
<size
    android:width="100dp"
    android:height="40dp"
    />
<!--<stroke
    android:width="3dp"
    android:color="#878787"
    />-->
```

And in my onCreate:

```
  @Override
protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.forgot_pass_layout);
    setTitle(getString(R.string.forgotpass));
    mail=findViewById(R.id.email);
    GradientDrawable bgShape3 = (GradientDrawable)mail.getBackground();
    bgShape3.setColor(getColor(R.color.white));
    scrollView=findViewById(R.id.scrollview);
    innerRl=findViewById(R.id.inner_rl);
    sendButton=findViewById(R.id.sendbutton);
    /*GradientDrawable bgShape = (GradientDrawable)sendButton.getBackground();
    bgShape.mutate();
    bgShape.setColor(getColor(R.color.white));*/
    //sendButton.setBackgroundColor(getColor(R.color.white));
    //GradientDrawable entrarShape=(GradientDrawable)sendButton.getBackground();
    //entrarShape.setColor(getColor(R.color.frontcolor));
    //entrar.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    //sendButton.setTextColor(getColor(R.color.white));
    sendButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            sendButton.setEnabled(false);
            String email=mail.getText().toString();
            if(Utils.isInternetAvailable(ForgotPassActivity.this)){
                DoRequest(email);
            }else{
                //No tenemos Internet. Mostramos el Toast
                Toast.makeText(ForgotPassActivity.this,getString(R.string.nointernet),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }

        }
    });
    backButton=findViewById(R.id.flecha);
    //GradientDrawable bgShape2 = (GradientDrawable)backButton.getBackground();
    //bgShape2.setColor(getColor(R.color.frontcolor));
    //backButton.setBackgroundColor(getColor(R.color.frontcolor));
    backButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            finish();
        }
    });
    sendButton.setEnabled(false);
    focusChangeListener=new View.OnFocusChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onFocusChange(final View v, boolean hasFocus) {

            if(hasFocus){
                scrollView.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        int scrollY = Math.max(0, innerRl.getHeight() - scrollView.getHeight());
                        scrollView.smoothScrollTo(0, scrollY);
                    }
                }, 200);
            }
        }
    };
    textWatcher=new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
            if(ValidateLogin(mail.getText().toString())){
                sendButton.setEnabled(true);
                sendButton.setAlpha(1F);
            }else{
                if(sendButton.isEnabled()){
                    sendButton.setEnabled(false);
                    sendButton.setAlpha(0.2F);
                }
            }
        }
    };
    mail.setOnFocusChangeListener(focusChangeListener);
    mail.addTextChangedListener(textWatcher);
    Toolbar toolbarTop =findViewById(R.id.toolbar_top);
    TextView mTitle = toolbarTop.findViewById(R.id.toolbar_title);
    mTitle.setText(getString(R.string.forgotpass));
    ImageView flecha=toolbarTop.findViewById(R.id.flecha);
    flecha.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            finish();
        }
    });
    setSupportActionBar(toolbarTop);
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
    getSupportActionBar().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(ContextCompat.getColor(this, R.color.frontcolor)));
    actionBar=getSupportActionBar();
}
```

I am getting the background of the button in the "frontcolor" color. Why is that, if I am setting white color in the drawable? How to set white color in the background of the button?

Comment: Are you using material theme?

Comment: Is it still not white when you set `alpha = 1` ?